# How to fix This event loop is already running error?

Tags: python, discord.py, event-loop

In my project I need to create many connections with discord bots. I have created a function for creating new thread that handles connection (so each thread sould handle one connection) but I am getting Runtime error: this event loop is already running (interesting that first thread is creating successfully and this error occures only while trying to create second thread). I have modified my code for test how to get around with this error and now I am trying to create two fully separate threads for separate connections on separate objects but I'm still getting this error. Actually I have no idea how to fix it...
My code is:

```
import discord
from threading import Thread

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
    async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)

thread1 = Thread(target=client.run, args=("TOKEN1", ))
thread1.start()



client2 = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)

thread2 = Thread(target=client2.run, args=("TOKEN2", ))
thread2.start()
```

(Tokens are present but hidden for obvious reasons)
Fist thread in this way creates successfully but when I'm trying to create second one it still thows errors: This event loop is already running, then: Cannot clos event loop, then: Event loop is closed

Comment: "In my project I need to create many connections with discord bots." Why? The entire point of the async setup is that a single bot will be able to respond to more commands while it waits on a lengthy calculation.

Comment: My program should work with completely different accounts. Logics of interaction with discord is not a problem. I think that the problem is somewhere with using python multithreading...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this, but here goes:

The issue is not with multithreading, but with the async loop (as your error suggests).

If you check out the source code, you will find, that if you don't pass a new async loop yourself, it will call the default `asyncio.get_event_loop()`, which seems like it causes some issues afterwards.

[https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#:~:text=..%20versionadded%3A%3A%202.0-,Attributes,](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#:%7E:text=..%20versionadded%3A%3A%202.0-,Attributes,))%3A,-%23%20self.ws%20is

(sorry, the link is broken, you have to copy it)

This answer seem to provide you with the info on how to create multiple loops: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31643784/13000953

So then you will have to create the two loops, and pass them as a parameter to your `discord.Client()`

```
loop1 = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop2 = asyncio.new_event_loop()

client1 = discord.Client(loop=loop1)
client2 = discord.Client(loop=loop2)
```